# Are there any relations between fractional calculus and fractional iteration?

Tags: reference-request, fractional-calculus, fractional-iteration

I wonder how the field of fractional calculus and the study of fractional iterates of functions relate to one another. I'm interested in cases in which techniques from the former field can be used to solve problems in the latter field, and vice versa. Any pointers to references are appreciated.

Comment: see my self-answers at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/does-the-formal-power-series-solution-to-ffx-sin-x-converge  including excerpted reply from Prof. Ecalle.  Read  Baker, including his obituary with related concepts discussed. One of his many: Baker, I. N. (1962). Permutable power series and regular iteration. J. Aust. Math. Soc., 2, 265–294.   The others were on one of my websites, on a server that crashed; but I can find copies here and email. The full length book by K,C,G,  is encyclopedic but unlikely to explicitly answer "I wonder" questions. I prefer Alexander for that.